# Reciprocals of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence, fibonacci-numbers

Is the sum of the reciprocals of Fibonacci numbers a transcendental?

Answer (score 27):

[The sum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html) is well-known (e.g., its decimal expansion is [OEIS A153386](https://oeis.org/A153386)), but
it seems(?) that although it is known to be irrational, and several special sums
of Fibonacci numbers are known to be transcendental, the *Reciprocal Fibonacci constant* itself (as it is known)
remains unsettled.

The paper
"Irrationality results for reciprocal sums of certain Lucas numbers"
by Paul-Georg Becker and Thomas Töpfer
([*Archiv der Mathematik*,
Volume 62, Number 4, 300-305, 1994](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01201780)),
says that Andre-Jeannin proved
(in "A note on the irrationality of certain Lucas infinite series," *Fibonacci Quart.*,
29, 132-136, 1991)
that the sum
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/R_n$,
where $R_{n+2}= a R_{n+1} + b R_n$,
is irrational,
and that Bundschuh and Väänänen [gave](http://archive.numdam.org/article/CM_1994__91_2_175_0.pdf) "an [irrationality measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html)" for this number.

For special cases, see
"Transcendence of reciprocal sums of binary recurrences"
by Tomoaki Kanoko, Takeshi Kurosawa and Iekata Shiokawa
([*Monatshefte für Mathematik*,
Volume 157, Number 4, 323-334, 2009](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00605-008-0073-z)),
and "Transcendence of Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction and reciprocal sums of Fibonacci numbers" by
Daniel Duverney, Keiji Nishioka, Kumiko Nishioka, and Iekata Shiokawa
([*Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci.*, Volume 73, Number 7 (1997), 140-142](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-73/issue-7/Transcendence-of-Rogers-Ramanujan-continued-fraction-and-reciprocal-sums-of/10.3792/pjaa.73.140.full)).
For example, the latter paper establishes that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{F_n^{2s}}$$
is transcendental for any positive integer $s$.

Answer (score 12):

To supplement Joseph's answer, I add my review MR2354148 on [C. Elsner, S. Shimomura and I. Shiokawa, *Acta Arith.* **130**:1 (2007), 37--60].

Let $\lbrace F_n\rbrace _{n\ge0}$ and $\lbrace L_n\rbrace _{n\ge0}$ be Fibonacci and Lucas numbers,
respectively,
$F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, $F_{n+2}=F_n+F_{n+1}$ for $n\ge0$, and
$L_0=2$, $L_1=1$, $L_{n+2}=L_n+L_{n+1}$ for $n\ge0$.
Using Nesterenko's theorem
[Yu.V. Nesterenko, *Sb. Math.* **187**:9 (1996), 1319--1348. MR1422383]
and expressing the series
$$
\zeta_F(2s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{F_n^{2s}}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\zeta_L(2s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{L_n^{2s}},
\qquad s=1,2,\dots,
\qquad (1)
$$
via the Eisenstein series
$$
E_{2s}(q)=1-\frac{4s}{B_{2s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sigma_{2s-1}(n)q^n,
\qquad \sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^k,
$$
where $B_{2s}\in\mathbb Q$ are Bernoulli numbers,
the authors prove the algebraic independence of
the numbers in the collections $\zeta_F(2)$, $\zeta_F(4)$, $\zeta_F(6)$
and $\zeta_L(2)$, $\zeta_L(4)$, $\zeta_L(6)$ as well as express
algebraically even "zeta values" $\zeta_F(2s)$ (and $\zeta_L(2s)$)
for $s\ge4$ in terms of the three algebraically independent numbers
in the corresponding collection. Similar algebraic independence results
are shown for the alternating versions of (1). Known irrationality
results for $\zeta_F(k)$ and $\zeta_L(k)$ with odd $k$
(when the series have no known relations with the modular world) are indicated.
It is worth mentioning that these results go in a natural parallel
with the ones for the so-called $q$-zeta values defined in
[[W. Zudilin, *Math. Notes* **72**:5-6 (2002), 858--862. MR1964151]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206179)
and [[C. Krattenthaler, T. Rivoal, and W. Zudilin,
*J. Inst. Math. Jussieu* **5**:1 (2006), 53--79. MR2195945]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311033).
In particular, it is natural to expect a "Fibonacci" analogue of Rivoal's theorem
[T. Rivoal, *C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Ser. I Math.* **331**:4 (2000), 267--270. MR1787183]
on the infiniteness of
irrational numbers in the set $\zeta_F(1),\zeta_F(3),\zeta_F(5),\dots$
(or $\zeta_L(1),\zeta_L(3),\zeta_L(5),\dots$),
based on the techniques developed in the paper under review and
in the joint paper of Krattenthaler, Rivoal and the reviewer cited above.

Reviewed by Wadim Zudilin

---

To summarize, the difficulty of proving the transcendence for odd $\zeta_F(s)$ with $s$ odd is similar to the one for odd zeta values. The irrationality of $\zeta_F(1)$ is known but already its non-quadraticity remains an open problem.

Answer (score 9):

Just to make the obvious comments:

Let $q = (1 - \sqrt{5})/2$. Then $F_n=((-q^{-1})^{n} - q^n)/\sqrt{5}$. So
$$\sum \frac{1}{F_n} = \sqrt{5} \sum \frac{q^n}{1-(-1)^n q^{2n}}.$$

This looks kind of like the logarithmic derivative of the modular form $\prod (1-q^n)$, but it's not exactly that. In any case, it is unlikely that someone has evaluated this sort-of-a-modular-form at this particular quadratic irrational. The natural thinkg to do is to evaluate modular forms when $\tau$ is a quadratic irrational, where $q=e^{2 \pi i \tau}$. For example, people might know what this sum equals at $q=e^{- \pi \sqrt{163}}$.

I'd be pleasantly surprised if there is a known answer. Of course, the safe money is always to bet on "transcendental" when you don't see a reason to expect anything else.

---

Looks like I was too pessimistic. It is known to be irrational, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html (thanks Qiaochu!). They do indeed describe this quantity in terms of theta functions, which are a type of modular forms. To my surprise, they are able to prove things about these modular forms at $q$, although not to answer this question. Anyway, it looks like this reference has as much information as you can hope for.

Comment: It's known to be irrational, but neither Wikipedia nor Mathworld says anything about its transcendentality.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like the mathworld page only gives a theta function formula for the sum of reciprocals of odd-indexed Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Actually, Richard André-Jeannin proved something somewhat stronger, namely that this constant doesn't belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. I was lucky enough to exchange with him on a French math forum, and I miss his kindness and delightful humor.