# Is $\pi$ well-approximable? 

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Is it known whether, for all $c > 0$, there always exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that
$\left| \pi - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{c}{q^2}$?

This seems like a fundamental question but I couldn't find a reference...

Comment: yes: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53724/are-some-numbers-more-irrational-than-others

Comment: This is a basic result from continued fractions. Any intro number theory text that has a section on cf's will contain this result.

Comment: @Kevin: It may be just my ignorance in the subject, but it would seem to me that the statement the OP wants would require the terms of the cf of $\pi$ to be unbounded, and this seems to be an open problem.

Comment: Note that the question asks for all $c>0$, not for some $c>0$.

Comment: Using the standard pigeonhole argument to show that there are infinitely many solutions for *some* $c$, the question would seem to reduce to the statement that the minimum distance between the first $n$ multiples of $\pi$ taken modulo 1 goes to zero faster than 1/n. That is, they are not too close to equally spaced. Certainly holds true for almost all real numbers, but I'm not aware of any theorem saying that it is true for $\pi$.

Comment: @Emil: you're right; I missed the "for all c" clause.

Comment: @Emil: Yes, that is an equivalent formulation.  Are the partial convergents in the cf of $\pi$ unbounded?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiContinuedFraction.html gives some information about this question, which seems to confirm that this is open.