# $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in\mathbb{N}} \sin(n)^{n^x}$ for various $x$

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Let  $$f(x)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in\mathbb{N}} \sin(n)^{n^x}.$$
Compute $f(1)$ and $f(2)$.

Answer (score 4):

In view of a result by Khinchine (see e.g. [Theorem 3.6(a)](https://www-ams-org.services.lib.mtu.edu/journals/tran/1961-099-01/S0002-9947-1961-0121357-5/)), there exist infinitely many pairs $(p,q)$ of natural numbers such that
$|2\pi q+\tfrac\pi2-p|<1/q$. For such $p$ and $q$, letting $q\to\infty$, we have $\sin p=1-O(1/q^2)=1-O(1/p^2)$ and hence $\sin^p p\to1$. So, $f(1)=1$.

---

As noted by [Gerald Edgar](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450769/limsup-n-rightarrow-infty-n-in-mathbbn-sinnnx-for-various-x/450775#comment1165116_450775), the same argument shows that $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in(0,2)$. For $x=2$, it seems we have to deal with Diophantine approximation to $\pi$, rather than that to a arbitrary irrational number. This seems to boil down to an open problem; cf. [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424166/36721).

Comment: Same argument for $1\le x < 2$.  But $x=2$ is on the border, this computation does not answer that case.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : You are quite right. For $x=2$, it seems we have to deal with Diophantine approximation to $\pi$, rather than that to a arbitrary irrational number. This seems to be an [open problem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424166/36721).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I found this problem on one of the t-shirts that were dustributed in a math competition about 10 years ago. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer to the second part of the problem either.

Comment: By the same argument with specifying the constant in $O(1/q^2)$, we may obtain a positive lower bound of $f(2)$.

Comment: @SungjinKim : Yes, you are right.