Natural functions outside $\sf PA$?
Can theories stronger than $\sf PA$ manage to define functions from the naturals to the naturals, that $\sf PA$ cannot? If so, what are examples of those functions?

Natural functions that are not arithmetically definable, but are definable in higher contexts, would include:  arithmetic truth, functions in the hyperarithmetic hierarchy, functions in the projective heirarchy, higher-order truth.  See also the hierarchy mentioned at https://mathoverflow.net/a/53754/1946

I wonder if the intended question is about functions that $\mathsf{PA}$ cannot prove total?

@TimothyChow, No. Here, the intended question is about natural functions that are not definable in PA but definable in higher systems.

Sure, but this is really a fact about structures rather than theories. For example, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can define the function sending $n$ to the least natural number not definable in the language of arithmetic by a sentence with length $<n$. But this function isn't definable in $\mathsf{PA}$ in any sense.
Now, what do I mean by saying that this is really a fact about structures rather than theories? First of all, note that there's actually a subtlety around my statement "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ can define:" what exactly does it mean for a theory, as opposed to a structure, to define a function? Here I mean that there is a formula in the language of set theory which we externally understand to correspond to (and which in any $\omega$-model actually defines) the function in question, and moreover $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that this function is total. But generally one needs to be very careful with language like "$T$ defines" etc.
What's really going on here is the following: whenever $\mathcal{M}$ is an $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (and under reasonable hypotheses there are many of these), there is a function on naturals which is not definable in $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ but whose translation into $\mathcal{M}$ (which makes sense here since $\mathcal{M}$ is an $\omega$-model) is definable in $\mathcal{M}$. Incidentally the "$\omega$-model" hypothesis is doing a ton of heavy lifting here. $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - and indeed any arithmetically definable consistent theory - also has arithmetically definable (necessarily non-$\omega$-)models. If $\mathcal{M}$ is such a model, then since $\mathcal{M}$ is interpretable in $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ there is no sense in which $\mathcal{M}$ can define a function that $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ can't.
We might try to escape the model-focus of the above paragraphs in the following way:

Given a theory $T$ with a distinguished interpretation $\Phi$ of Robinson arithmetic, say that a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is invariantly $T$-definable iff there is some formula $\varphi(x,y)$ such that for every $\mathcal{M}\models T$ and every standard natural number $n$ we have $$\mathcal M \models \forall y[\varphi(\Phi(n), y)\leftrightarrow y=\Phi(f(x))].$$

Unfortunately, this is boring: as long as $T$ is "reasonable" (e.g. $\mathsf{Q}$, $\mathsf{PA}$, $\mathsf{ZFC}$, ...) we will always have the invariantly $T$-definable functions be exactly the computable functions. This was first observed by Kreisel and further developed by Moschovakis and others; see also here for a bit more on invariant definability.
